# fix underline when applying page-break CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic table with 2px solid border in my web page that sometimes contains lots of rows. I am currently using  `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` CSS properties.

The CSS code is as per below:

```
            table { page-break-inside:auto }
            tr    { page-break-inside: avoid; page-break-after:auto }
            table.table-bordered{
                width: 100%;
                border:2px solid black;
                margin-top:20px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
              }
              table.table-bordered td{
                padding: 6px;
                border:2px solid black;
                margin-top:20px;
              }
```

The main problem is, it is showing underline when page breaks.

[image: underline break when page ends]

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.